# Two Brushes, same Image, but one with opacity

Tags: wpf, imagebrush

I have two Imagebrushes, as you see they are exactly the same but one is with opacity.

```xaml
<ImageBrush x:Key="One" ImageSource="AluSilver.jpg" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,200,200" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Opacity="0.5" />

<ImageBrush x:Key="Two" ImageSource="AluSilver.jpg" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,200,200" ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
```

Since Brushes are not styleable I must create these two.

Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: Maybe you're applying the opacity at a too low level (i.e. the brush) instead of applying it to the control using the brush ?

Comment: Set the opacity on control where this brush is getting applied eventually. (May be over `Image` control).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you doing all that because brushes allow manipulation.

Take a look at this:

```
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100">
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="MyAnimatedBrush" Color="Orange" />
  </Rectangle.Fill>
  <Rectangle.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.MouseLeftButtonDown">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedBrush"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0.5" AutoReverse="True" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>        
  </Rectangle.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```

You may change opacity as well as color or whatever you need.